# Generate private key & public key in my case

Tags: java, java-security, key-pair, key-generator

I need to create a function which could always generate the same private key/public key every time it is called.

Here is my function code I created:

```
public void generateTheUniqueKeys() {
    KeyPairGenerator keyGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    keyGenerator.initialize(512);
    KeyPair keyPair = keyGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    // I need every time when this function is called, it generate the same keys as that generated from previous call
    PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
    PublicKey pubKey = keyPair.getPublic();
}
```

How can I make my function to always generated the same key pair?

Comment: I don't have an answer but my attempt at this put me deep into the Java Security package and it wasn't pretty.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the keys once and store in a file so the function always retrieve the same key pair from the file.

Comment: The precondition of my question is this file could be deleted, and I want to restore it by generate the same key pairs.

Comment: I don't see the point trying to generate the same key pairs with a function. The whole point of generating a key pair is that it is different. Why no just store and return the same key? Could you share a little background? Are you trying to write a unit test or something?